# What is it called when $f_{xx}=f_{yy}$ and $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The function $f(x,y) = x^2y + 2xy + xy^2$ has the properties such that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$. Is there a name for the types of functions which satisfy this? Does one equality imply the other?

Also, is there any importance to those equalities, or is it just a pretty coincidence?

Comment: The second equality is due to Young's theorem, and always holds. The first is the like a harmonic function with a condition $\Delta f(x,iy)=0$, I don't know a name for that.

Comment: Wouldn't satisfying Laplace's equation (if that's what you meant) mean that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$?

Comment: @ÁkosSomogyi I wouldn't say that the second equality *always* holds.  Continuity of the second derivatives in a neighborhood of the point at which you're evaluating them is a sufficient condition, which holds often (in practice) but not always.

Comment: $f_{xx} = f_{yy}$ is called the wave equation.

Comment: It's not true that $f_{xx}=f_{yy}$ --- $f_{xx}=2y$ and $f_{yy}=2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry? I don't think any other name exists.